# Replace parts of files

Tags: scripting, password, replace

I'm quite new in the linux world.
I've got a file containing Usernames and Passwords, for browser authentications.
eg.:

```
user:ioeuwz5rf (Password generated with "openssl passwd ABCXYZ")
```

Now, I want these passwords to get changed automatically every week or whatever.

I tried it with a change.sh file containing:

```
newpw="`openssl passwd ABCXYZ`"
sed -i 's/WhatToReplace/'$newpw'/g' test.txt
```

This would replace the word "WhatToReplace" with the generated pw.
But I want to do it automatically. Is there a way to replace the 2nd part  (user:**ioeuwz5rf**) with the random password.

I want a new random password generated for every user, and this should be saved into a file (newpw.txt eg.) from which I can generate mails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of replacing all lines in `newpw.txt`,
it would be better to create a new file by iterating over the usernames in the old one, for example:

```
cut -d: -f1 pw.txt | while read -r user; do
    echo "$user:$(openssl passwd ABCXYZ)"
done > newpw.txt
mv newpw.txt pw.txt
```

Comment: In addition, i think the mention of `cron` must be here. If author want to really automate the process, he should meet with `cron` and `crontab`.

Comment: Thank you, i just have another few questions, may you can help there as well? For sure i would run it with a Cronjob :)