# Password change Script

Tags: linux, scripting, cron, password

i am having a file, which contains usernames and encrypted passwords (openssl passwd) in the format user:password.
Now i want to change the password of this User with a Cronjob once a week.
With the help of [Janos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/17433/janos) i made a Script, which changes the password to a $RANDOM generated value, and saves the encrypted password in pw.txt, and the non-encrypted in randompw.txt

```
r=$RANDOM
cut -d: -f1 pw.txt | while read -r user; do
    echo "$user:$(openssl passwd $r)"
done > newpw.txt
mv newpw.txt pw.txt
echo $r > randompw.txt
```

So my problems are:
1.) With this, i just have a random generated value for each users, but i want a random value for each user (each line in the file).
2.) It would be good, if i can get the username and the cleartext password of each user into randompw.txt currently, i just have one $RANDOM Password there.

Does anyone has an Idea?

[Old post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335230/replace-parts-of-files/335349#335349)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the generated password in a variable, and write it two files:

- One file in clear
- One file hashed

For example:

```
# initialize (truncate) output files
> clear.txt
> hashed.txt

cut -d: -f1 pw.txt | while read -r user; do        
    # generate a hash from a random number
    hash=$(openssl passwd $RANDOM)

    # use the first 8 letters of the hash as the password
    pass=${hash:0:8}

    # write password in clear formats to one file, and hashed in another
    echo "$user:$pass" >> clear.txt
    echo "$user:$(openssl passwd $pass)" >> hashed.txt
done
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect! No im just trying to generate Emails out of it, i hope i get it. :)

Comment: Next question about this topic: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335390/generate-e-mails-with-content-on-different-files

Comment: @Manu_H that question is likely to get closed, as this is not a script writing service. If you try to implement it and get stuck, post the partially working code, and then somebody will probably help you finish it.