# Generate E-Mails with content on different files

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, scripting, password

i am using a script to create a random password for a user.
The file looks like

```
user1:password1
user2:password2
user3:password3
```

Passwords are openssl passwd hashed. I have an own file where the password is written in cleartext.
No i want to send an E-Mail to the users with the new password.
I have a file (maillist.txt) with

```
user1:mail@domain1.tld
user2:mail@domain2.tld
user3:mail@domain3.tld
```

Now i want to generate an E-Mail to user1.
This should generate an E-Mail to mail@domain1.tld, containing the username (user1) and the password (password1).  I want to do it with mailx.
Can you please help me?

Regards
Manu
[Old post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335358/need-help-for-a-password-change-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
join -t: cleartext.txt maillist.txt | awk -F: '{ print "echo Username: "$1" Passwd: "$2" | mailx -s Information "$3 }' |sh
```

If multi lines are required in the email body, refer below

```
#!/bin/bash
>tmp.txt
join -t: cleartext.txt maillist.txt | while read line
do
  echo $line
  USER=$(echo $line | awk -F: '{ print $1 }')
  PSWD=$(echo $line | awk -F: '{ print $2 }')
  EMAILID=$(echo $line | awk -F: '{ print $3 }')
  echo "Hello $(echo $USER | tr a-z A-Z), your password has been changed!!!<br>" >tmp.txt
  echo "<b>Username</b>: $USER<br>" >>tmp.txt
  echo "<b>Password</b>: $PSWD<br>" >> tmp.txt
  cat tmp.txt | mailx -s "$(echo -e 'Password Changed!!!\nContent-Type: text/html')" $EMAILID
done
```

Comment: Is it possible to add something to the text? Something like "Hello your password has been changed" and something after the text? If i do {  print "echo Blablabla \n test Username: ...} i get an unexpected error?

Comment: Updated the answer for multi lines in email body.